# What is the recommended maximum file size for a social media type website?

Tags: images, file-size

I am building a social media app for gardeners. One of the things they can do is upload images of their gardens. I am storing everything in Amazon aws s3.

I don't want the user to be able to upload large image files because if those images are then displayed on a webpage they may cause that webpage to load slow.

Most images will be displayed in an image carousel that contains a row of image thumbnails, an image preview section, and when you press on the image preview an enlarged image will be shown.

So if a webpage can contain multiple images what filesize limit would be recommended?

Comment: If you allow other people to view the originally uploaded image, make sure to at least sanitize its metadata first. Images can contain a lot of extra data that you don't necessarily want other people seeing, like the GPS coordinates of where the image was taken.

Comment: I was aware of this @Yay925, its called exif data. But thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a sized-down version of each image that you use for the thumbnails. That way, nobody will use a large amount of bandwidth until they explicitly click on an image to enlarge it.

As for the full-size images, it all depends on how much you value high-res images versus performance. On the low end, consider a 1MB limit each. On the high end, maybe 3-5 MB at the most.

Comment: You don't even have to show the original image when it's enlarged. There could be a download button to get the original image, but all copies actually displayed on the site could be shrunk.